# Enterprise architect (Sparx System) - Documentation template for UseCase

Tags: templates, documentation-generation, enterprise-architect

I need help with creating UseCase template for Enterprise Architect (v 12.1). I have UseCase diagram like this one and I need to generate documentation from diagram named "Transaction" (as you can see on this picture):

[image: My diagram]

The problem is, that one UseCase is located in another package. When generating documentation with my template (I need only " Transaction" package in my documentation not Transaction Validation or other packages), the UseCase of Transaction Validation is not generated (simply because of this element is from another package).

One more note - we don't write Structured Specification Scenario, but we write scenarions into "Description" tab. Like this one:

[image: Scenario]

I tried to create template for generating elements located on diagram, but there is only option to generate Element.StructuredScenarioText for "foreign" element located on diagram when creating template (I need the red one values - ElemScenario.Scenario, ElemScenario.Type and ElemScenario.Notes):

[image: Template]

Is there any option to generate Scenario (not structured) for "foreign" UseCase located on diagram?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the description from an element's scenarios, select the RTF template section `package / element / scenario` and insert the `Notes` field.

Your other issue, how to include elements from other packages in a report, is a little trickier.

Normally you would base the template on the diagram and make sure you select **Include all Diagram Elements in Report** in the Generate Documentation dialog.

The problem in this case is that when you document elements in the context of a diagram, you only have access to a limited subset of the element fields. For scenarios, you're limited to the `Element.StructuredScenarioText` field, which in your case is empty. The same limited set of fields is available if you document elements in the context of a connector, ie elements connected to the element being documented, so you can't use that either.

The simplest option is to create a template fragment. With fragments you can implement your own selection using an SQL query or a custom script, and thus free your document from the package hierarchy.

Alternatively, you can run the generation from a higher package level which includes all your use cases (in your case, "Transactions in WO"), and add a filter in the Generate Documentation dialog to select only those use cases you want.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a virtual document. You can then use an (SQL) search to get the use cases you need, or even make one model document for each use case.

Comment: That is indeed another option, but I think it's a bigger change than adding a fragment so I didn't include it.